# error reported when writing influx line protocol data to TDengine

Tags: influxdb, tdengine

the request body is something like:

```
type_61e753468ecb3800497311bd_19gqMPJ3Os1,ct_name=ct_type_19gqMPJ3Oso_19gBnvupzB6,deviceId=19gBnvupzB6 La$f=257.65,Timestamp$f=1650607683.76,assetId=L"nx_devzy001_inst02",calculate_time=1650607683880i,cloud_time=1650607683781i,create_time=1650607683762i,metricsType=0i,write_time=1650610367037i,bool_test$b=true,duration$i=10i,int_test$i=-46i,la$f=78.0,lb$f=78.0,lc$f=29.0,number_test$f=-46.0,string_test$s=L"Hello你好！",times_int_val$i=1650607683762i,workstatus$i=1i 1650607683762
```

I got the error is "internal error" and "[0x362] Table does not exist"

Environment (please complete the following information):

```
TDengine Version ：2.4.0.16
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your line protocol there's (currently treated as) duplicat column name `La` and `la`, use a different name `la2` will fix the problem by now.

You can also look up to the bugfix of the problem then.

Comment: yes, I use it and the problem is disappearing now.